# Setting up a session cookie

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up a 'session' cookie with Google Tag Manager, but im struggling with the code itself. I thought that this code is enough

`<script>
document.cookie = 'daction=true';
</script>`

But it seems that the cookie stays even I close the browser, what would be the correct code for setting up a session cookie?